# How to handle multiple validations on submit (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Hi there, I need to validate several inputs before letting the user submit:**

```
  <button type="submit" v-on:click="validateErrors()" @click.prevent="submit">Finalizar</button>
```

**I did a method `validateErrors` in order to handle all of the validations separately:**

```
   validateErrors() {
     if (this.campaign.selectedBox == null) {
      this.$set(this.msg, 'selectedbox', 'Alert 1') ;
      return true;
     }
     if (this.campaign.selectedExtras == null) {
      this.$set(this.msg, 'selectedextras', 'Alert 2') ;
      return true;
     }
   },
```

**Lastly, I made an alert with the different messages to show in case one (or various) of the inputs don't validate:**

```
<div class="alert alert-info w-100" v-if="msg.selectedbox">{{msg.selectedbox}}</div>
<div class="alert alert-info w-100" v-if="msg.selectedextras">{{msg.selectedextras}}</div>
```

**Only the first of the validations is working, how can I handle multiple validations with their own alerts being executed by the same function on submit?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove `return` statements from each loop will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating this function  you can add rules for the input and then use form validator in vuejs
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html
But if you want to stay using this function you can do this

```
function validateErrors() {
  var check1 = false;
  var check2 = false;
  if (this.campaign.selectedBox == null) {
    this.$set(this.msg, "selectedbox", "Alert 1");
    check1 = true;
  }
  if (this.campaign.selectedExtras == null) {
    this.$set(this.msg, "selectedextras", "Alert 2");
    check2 = true;
  }
  return {check1:check1, check2:check2};
}
```